# How to include <linux/timer.h> head file in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, kernel, compiling, gcc, make

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel-4.15. When I include the header file `<linux/timer.h>` in the source code, the header file cannot be found:`fatal error: linux/timer.h: No such file or directory`. 
Then I include the source file of `timer.h` by adding `-I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/include` to the cmdline of gcc. However, another error occurs because missing another header file: `fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory`. Now, I don't know how to include `linkage.h` because there are so many of them.

`wpf@wpf-KLV-WX9:~/Desktop/BDFuzzer$ sudo find / f -name "linkage.h"
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/include/linux/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/include/asm-generic/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/metag/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/arm64/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/m32r/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/frv/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/nios2/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/tile/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/alpha/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/ia64/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/parisc/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/c6x/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/score/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/blackfin/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/m68k/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/arc/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/hexagon/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/arm/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/openrisc/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/s390/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/riscv/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/mips/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/mn10300/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/sh/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/unicore32/include/asm/linkage.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/powerpc/include/asm/linkage.h`

Since I'm using a x86-64 machine, I selected `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-91/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h`, but plenty of error occurs, too.

I have also tried 
`apt-get install libc-dev`, 
`apt-get install build-essential`, 
and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, 
but none of them worked. Can anyone please tell me how to use  properly?

Comment: If you are compiling the kernel, it expects to find the file in the source tree at `include/linux/timer.h`. If it is not there, then other areas of the kernel will not compile either. Suggested procediure for compiling the kernel is to first compile it with no changes at all,just to prove you can, then make changes.

Comment: The header file `timer.h` is indeed at the source tree. I'm not compiling the kernel. I'm writing a user application based on the timer function of the kernel, thus, I need to include `<linux\timer.h>`.

Comment: well, good luck with that. Myself, I think it is too integrated with the kernel itself to be be used independently. The normal user `tiimer.h` file should be included with just `#include <time.h>` and/or `#include <sys/time.h>`

Comment: Do you have `linux-headers-generic` package installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed them by `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`